# calculate a dynamic scenario in python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class calculation():
    def __init__(self):
        print("in self")
     
    def calculate_by_id(self):
        print("in id")
 
    def calculate_by_name(self):
        print("name")
```

hi I am writing a program and I want something like I have 4 parameters . name , id , batch_id , weight . I want to just pass data of these 4 and in return want to get function called in a way like  if name is empty string it should called  `calculate_by_id`   and if id is empty `calculate_by_name` should be called .

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want a single function that can take four parameters?

Comment: @wkl yes like every calculation on basis of condition either id is empty or name is empty

Comment: What happens if someone specifies more than one parameter?

Comment: @wkl there will always 4 total parameters . and two are id and name on which class with decide which function to call

Answer (score 0):

```
class Calculation():
    def __init__(self, name, id, batch_id, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.batch_id = batch_id
        self.weight = weight
     
    def calculate_by_id(self):
        print("in id")
 
    def calculate_by_name(self):
        print("name")
```

This will allow you to save information in a Calculation object. Although I'm not quite sure what exactly you are looking for and will update this as more information is given.

Comment: thanks for answer , but 2nd part of my question that how I will call function like if id is empty I have to call  calculate_by_name  and if name is empty it will call calculate_by_id